# How can I solve for x when there is an exponent on both sides?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, convergence-divergence

I want to solve for $x$ in the following equation $$\left(f_{1}\left(m+z\right)-f_{1}\left(m-z\right)\right)=\left(\left(n_{f2}-(n_{f2}-f_{3}(0))(1-x)^{\left(z\right)}\right)-\left(n_{f2}-(n_{f2}-f_{3}(0))(1-x)^{\left(-z\right)}\right)\right)$$

No matter what I do to the equation, I can't figure out how to isolate $x$

The following are the constraints for the above variables:

$i$ is the input to a function.

$f_1(0)\in[-\infty, \infty]$

$n_{f1}\in[-\infty, \infty]$

$r_1\in[0,1]$

$f_2(0)\in[-\infty, \infty]$

$n_{f2}\in[-\infty, \infty]$

$f_1(i)=n_{f1}−(n_{f1}-f_1(0))(1−r_1)^i$

$f_2(i)=n_{f2}−(n_{f2}-f_2(0))(1−x)^i$

$z=0.001$

A value $m$ can be derived where $m$ is the input to $f_1$ that outputs $f_2(0)$
$n_{f1}-(n_{f1}-f_{1}\left(0\right))(1-r_{1})^{m}=f_{2}\left(0\right)$

$-(n_{f1}-f_{1}\left(0\right))(1-r_{1})^{m}=f_{2}\left(0\right)-n_{f1}$

$(-n_{f1}+f_{1}\left(0\right))(1-r_{1})^{m}=f_{2}\left(0\right)-n_{f1}$

$\left(f_{10}-f_{1}\left(0\right)\right)\left(1-r_{1}\right)^{m}=f_{2}\left(0\right)-n_{f1}$

$\left(1-r_{1}\right)^{m}=\left(\frac{f_{2}\left(0\right)-n_{f1}}{f_{1}\left(0\right)-n_{f1}}\right)$

$m=\log_{(1-r_{1})}\left(\frac{f_2(2)-n_{f1}}{f_1(0)-n_{f1}}\right)$

thus, a third function, where $f_1(m) = f_3(m)$ can be derived
$n_{f1}-(n_{f1}-f_{1}\left(0\right))(1-r_{1})^{m}=f_{2}\left(0\right)$

Essentially, they just intersect when $y = f_2(0)$. Then, I derived that

$s_{1}=\frac{\left(f_{1}\left(m+z\right)-f_{1}\left(m-z\right)\right)}{2z}$

$s_{2}=\frac{\left(f_{2}\left(m+z\right)-f_{2}\left(m-z\right)\right)}{2z}$

where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are very near approximations for the slope where $i=m$

I then set them equal to each other

$\frac{\left(f_{1}\left(m+z\right)-f_{1}\left(m-z\right)\right)}{2z} = \frac{\left(f_{2}\left(m+z\right)-f_{2}\left(m-z\right)\right)}{2z}$

I then substituted f_2 for its value and multiplied by 2z

$\left(f_{1}\left(m+z\right)-f_{1}\left(m-z\right)\right)=\left(\left(n_{f2}-(n_{f2}-f_{3}(0))(1-x)^{\left(z\right)}\right)-\left(n_{f2}-(n_{f2}-f_{3}(0))(1-x)^{\left(-z\right)}\right)\right)$

How can I solve for x? According to desmos, there is definitely a value of x assuming the above constraints, but I can't seem to derive the exact value of x. Any help would be appreciated.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8ajtbggx9i

Comment: I think you'll get a better response if you declutter things a bit. In trying to read over what you've written, I'm not even sure what equation and variable you want solved. For example, where you wrote "I've derived that", I don't see how that follows from what you've given thus far, and if this is simply an equation we're to assume holds, then say so. Moreover, before I even got past the first equation, I see $n_{f1}-f_1(0)$ which, according to your variable/constant values, could be $\infty - \infty.$ Maybe explain what it is you're working on to help orient us with the proper context.

Comment: My goal is to isolate the variables $x$. Sorry I had a major oversight in describing how I derived m, because I had mistaken what its significance was. The equation I want to solve is the one at the very top, where my goal is to solve for x. Everything else is just a description of what each variable signifies. To be honest, I wasn't sure what parts of the question was important until I had written it all out. I explained how I derived m, and moved the actual equation to the top.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you essentially have an equation of the form $a X + b X^{-1} = c$ (where $a,b,c$ result from the variables that do not involve $x$ and $X = (1-x)^z$) and try to solve for $X$ (since then you get to $x$ via $x = \sqrt[z]{X}-1$). Is that correct?